# Discovery service unable to fetch the config details from Configuration-service

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, service-discovery

I am following complete tutorial from the link: https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2018/04/26/quick-guide-to-microservices-with-spring-boot-2-0-eureka-and-spring-cloud/ and in this tutorial I've upgraded s`pring-boot-starter-parent` to `2.1.3.RELEASE` and `spring-cloud-dependencies` version to `Greenwich.SR1`.

**config-service** I've started successfully on port `8088`, but when I start the `discovery-service`, it's not `Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8088.`

I run the config-service with the

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=native
```

File System

```
$ ls -ltr
total 10
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 1049089 233 Apr  2 09:45 discovery-service.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 1049089 212 Apr  2 09:45 employee-service.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 1049089 206 Apr  2 09:45 employee-service-instance2.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 1049089 925 Apr  2 09:45 gateway-service.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 1049089 212 Apr  2 09:45 organization-service.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 1049089 486 Apr  2 09:45 proxy-service.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 1049089 212 Apr  2 09:45 department-service.yml
```

Comment: Regardless of the tutorial, please share your configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by adding correct ***spring-cloud-starter-config***

Here is the dependency that you need to add -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```